# add dynamically edittext in dialogue

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-edittext, android-dialog

I am trying to add edittext in dialogue one below others or above others but when I am trying to add edittext in my dialogue then it  is coming above of each new edit text. what I am getting this ....
[image: dialogue getting]

But I am wanted this way .....
[image: dialogue needed]

when I am clicking on image add button then new textview should added in screen. I have written a code as follows ...

```
final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        try {
            Log.w("Addfriendsactivity", "friendsCount--first time-> "+friendsCount);
        friendsCount++;
        EditText textview = new EditText(context);
        Log.w("Addfriendsactivity", "friendsCount---> "+friendsCount);
        textview.setId(friendsCount);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, friendsCount--);
        friendsCount += 1;
        Log.w("Addfriendsactivity", "friendsCount--third time-> "+friendsCount);
        textview.setLayoutParams(params);
        textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.w("Addfriendsactivity", "params---> "+params);
        Log.w("Addfriendsactivity", "textview---> "+textview);
        Log.w("Addfriendsactivity", "relativelayout--> "+textview);
        dialog.addContentView(textview ,params);
        textview.setText(String.valueOf(friendsCount));
        Log.d("addFriendsActivity", "ashish comes here ");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }); 
}
```

Can any one help me on this why this is happening how to come out from this issues ?
Thanks in advance..

**EDIT**

my XML layout is as follows

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#FFFFFF"
  tools:context=".AddFriendsCustomActivity" >

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/writename"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit_dialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/writename"
    android:layout_below="@+id/add"
    android:layout_marginRight="46dp"
    android:text="Submit" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/writename"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/writename"
    android:contentDescription="Add Friend"
    android:src="@drawable/add" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Implement LinearLayout with Vertical orientation instead of RelativeLayou. Just try this

Comment: @MD can you tell where and what link ?

Answer (score 0):

Place this line - 
final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); inside button's click event.See this:

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            Log.w("Addfriendsactivity", "friendsCount--first time-> "
                    + friendsCount);
            friendsCount++;
            EditText textview = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
            Log.w("Addfriendsactivity", "friendsCount---> " + friendsCount);
            if (friendsCount == 2) {
                textview.setId(friendsCount);
            } else {
                textview.setId(friendsCount);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, textview.getId() - 1);
            }

            // friendsCount += 1;
            Log.w("Addfriendsactivity", "friendsCount--third time-> "
                    + (textview.getId() - 1));
            textview.setLayoutParams(params);
            textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Log.w("Addfriendsactivity", "params---> " + params);
            Log.w("Addfriendsactivity", "textview---> " + textview);
            Log.w("Addfriendsactivity", "relativelayout--> " + textview);
            dialog.addView(textview);
            textview.setText(String.valueOf(friendsCount));

            Log.d("addFriendsActivity", "ashish comes here ");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I just create example which create `EditText` when user click on `Button`. Check it out and update it as per your requirement.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:onClick="ShowDialog"
        android:text="Click Me" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**layout_row.xml(For dialog layout)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutmain"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnadd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="add EditText" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void ShowDialog(View v) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dialog!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_row);
        dialog.setTitle("Title...");
        final LinearLayout layoutmain = (LinearLayout) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.layoutmain);
        Button btnadd = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
        btnadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                EditText myedittext = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                layoutmain.addView(myedittext);
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }

}
```

**Output :**

[image]
[image]

Comment: it  is showing me null pointer error on relai during add view method